# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I have created an ASP.NET web application using Visual Studio 2022 and C#. I have created a separate class library using Visual Studio 2022 and C#. In this class library, I have added a Machine Learning model. I have trained the model and obtained all the required files. I am trying to deploy this model into my ASP .NET web application.

I have added a reference to the class library in the references of the ASP web project. When I am trying to predict the results from one of the Web Forms, I am getting this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is the code I used to obtain the prediction results

```
var sampleData = new MLModel1.ModelInput()
            {
                Mood = @"happy",
                Smell = @"rosegarden",
                Place = @"mountain",
                Drink = @"mojito",
                Category = @"trending",
                Gender = @"unisex",
                Time = @"both",
                Occasion = @"special",
                Feel = @"elegant",
                Ingredientsp1 = @"woody",
                Ingredientsp2 = @"ip5",
            };

var result = MLModel1.Predict(sampleData).ToString();
```

I am providing the input data and calling the `Predict` method to get the results. The target .NET framework for the web application is 4.8. The framework for the class library is .NET 6.0.

I deployed the ML model as a console app and it worked perfectly. But I am trying to use it in my web application so that I can get input from the users using the various controls like textboxes and button and then pass the values as input to the ML model.

Comment: Is your ASP.NET Web Application targeting .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: yes the FRAMEWORK is 4.8

Comment: `System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0` tagets .NET6, so this might be the problem.

Comment: How do I change the target Framework? I have only 3 options available—framework - 4.6, 4.7.2 and 4.8

Comment: Switching from a .NET Framework to a .NET project requires more than just changing a setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/